# altruism in a negative context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can altruism be used in a negative context to show a person doing something bad but unselfishly. He did such and such quite altruistically actually. Its meant to be tongue in cheek. Does that work?

Comment: Yes. A *lie of omission* (or actually, even a *lie* in itself) can be considered altruistic for example. *"Although I wanted to tell her that I ran into her ex this morning, I lied about it for her own good."*

Comment: amoose wants something "bad but unselfish". But, there is nothing bad about keeping the peace.

Comment: There's no problem with your sentence and no issue with an altruistic act being considered bad by someone other than the actor (at the time of the act). It does sound a bit formal though, informally one might say "he meant well" instead. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "tongue-in-cheek" though. Do you mean that the speaker is supposed to be implying that it may not have actually been altruistic?

Answer (score 1):

[Altruism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/altruism):

> - the principle or practice of unselfish concern for or devotion to the welfare of others (opposed to egoism.
> - a concern or regard for the needs of others, entirely without ulterior motive.

Being the object of altruism the needs or welfare of others, the means by which one can benefit other people may be different and controversial too.
As suggested, a lie can be considered an altruistic act if  it  benefits a person or a situation. Taken to extremes, even a suicide may be considered as such. I am thinking about the Japanese 'kamikaze'. If what people do with altruistic intentions  can be considered  as '[true](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altruism)' altruism is still a matter of debate.

Answer (score 0):

As it is rather a *philosophical question*, I feel some right to answer even if I am not a native English speaker.

In Czech, we have a funny phrase *páchat dobré skutky*, which may be word-by-word translated to *commit good deeds*.

I would say about such a person:

> She is such a f***ing altruist!

The meaning is that she does what usually is done by altruists, but without thinking of the consequences and the actual added value for the *objects* of her actions. It is in fact egoistic, but you asked for a use case for "altruism" with negative connotation and here I think is one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a euphemism when one uses a word or statement in a positive way with a negative connotation so as not to seem inconsiderate or complicit.